# 'google-cloud-firestore' distribution doesn't get added to PyInstaller build

Tags: python, firebase, pyinstaller

When I am trying to build an executable for my python script it gives me:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-firestore' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I've created the following hooks: 'hook-google-cloud-firestore.py' and 'hook-google.cloud.py', but it doesn't seem to help either. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Seeing the same problem when installed by Home Assistant internally.

Answer (score 9):

for two days, i have found the solution with three steps

## FIRST

in `hook-google.cloud` add this code.

```
datas += copy_metadata('google-cloud-firestore')
```

root of `hook-google.cloud.py`
..

```
C:\Users\ASPIREone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks
```

## SECOND

make

```
hook-google-cloud-firestore.py
```

in root of:

```
C:\Users\ASPIREone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks
```

and add this code

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata, get_package_dir
datas += copy_metadata('google-cloud-firestore')
datas += copy_metadata('google_cloud_firestore')  #altlll

hiddenimports += ['google-cloud-firestore_v1']
#pythonhosted.org/pyinstaller/hooks.html#understanding-pyinstaller-hooks
#get_package_dir returns tuple (where pkg stored, abs path to pkg)
pkg_dir = 'C:/Users/ASPIREone/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Lib/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1'

datas += (pkg_dir, 'google-cloud-firestore')
```

don't forget to delete folder `__pycache__` in your main project my main project is root of  `C:\Users\ASPIREone\PycharmProjects\amazon\parking-go`

## third

delete your app (example: main.exe) in root of:

```
C:\Users\ASPIREone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\dist
```

go to command line

don't use `pyinstaller.exe --onefile main.py` but use

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --clean main.py`

because m main proect in root folder so i write in command line:

`pyinstaller.exe --onefile --clean C:\Users\ASPIREone\PycharmProjects\amazon\parking-go\main.py`

you have to clean it and rebuild from first

it should work !

## .........

if you have an error when your app running when retrieve data or write to firestore like this:

```
Exception ignored in: 'grpc._cython.cygrpc.ssl_roots_override_callback'
E0527 07:10:01.571000000  3672 src/core/lib/security/security_connector/ssl_util
s.cc:449] assertion failed: pem_root_certs != nullptr
```

## it solved with this step:

## copy file `roots.pm` into your **main project** or `where you run your app`

dir of `roots.pm` is

```
C:\Users\ASPIREone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\grpc\_cython\_credentials\roots.pm
```

## make `hook-grpc.py` and put this code

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('grpc')
```

go to commandline

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --clean yourmainfile.py
```

it should work !

Answer (score 0):

Recently i found a solution for this,hope this will fix your problem too.

Create two hook files:

1. hook-google.cloud.firestore.py
2. hook-grpc.py

In **hook-google.cloud.firestore.py** write below code and save it somewhere:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata
datas = copy_metadata('google-cloud-firestore')
```

In **hook-grpc.py** write below code and save it at same place:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files ( 'grpc' )
```

Now copy paste both the files to :

C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

If you still face the problem, Please use setuptools version 45.0.0 and then run pyinstaller and create your exe file by:

pyinstaller --clean --onefile yourfilename.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to locate `hooks-google.cloud.py` in the PyInstaller package, you can try to locate it in:

```
C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks
```

or if you are using a virtual environment, you can look for `_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks` instead if you are using it to build the exe file.

If the error still persists, you can take a look at the build log to locate where `hook-google.cloud.py` is built from.

I hope this helps somebody out in the future as it works for me.